# The admin doesn't get emailed when a customer orders something on magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, email

I have a problem with magento webshop. The order emails are not being send to customers and admin. I dont know where the file is where this is programmed and how to change it. I've also read online that it might be a cron issue so here is my cron config on magento backend.

[image: cron config]

Comment: Is your cron setup on the server ?

Comment: where could you see this

Answer (score 1):

See this https://blog.amasty.com/configure-magento-cron-job/ to set up cron and solve this problem

Comment: Its best not to link to articles, and post the full answer. However this link has all the relevant information on it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, there was a cronjob disabled on the server. We called the hosting company and they turned it on. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can also accept your own answer ;)